# Differentiate between property and method with same name

Tags: javascript, prototype, naming

If I have a variable named `format` and a method with the same name, how would I go about calling the variable, and the method?

```
use strict;

function Time() {
    this.format = 'x:y:z';
}

Time.prototype = {
    format: function (format) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot - name them differently

Comment: Impossible. The method is overwritten.

Comment: A better question would be for you to explain *why* you would need this behavior. You of course *can* write code wrongly, code that interferes with itself, but why would you? The code is simply written to fail.

Comment: @Jhawins This code was not written to fail. The reason why I wanted it like this was because I just couldn't think of a better names, and was wondering if it was possible in some kind of way.

Comment: @KidDiamond it's kind of like doing `foo = 9; (function() { var foo = 5; return foo; })()` and expecting to return 9. There's just no sense in it :P. There *is* a `foo` that is 9, but you won't be referencing it.

Comment: @Jhawins Might be, but when I logged the object in the console I saw that it both contained the variable **and** the function. So I thought there would be a way to call them regardless of the same name,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't usually do this, because there is no difference in JavaScript between a *method* and a *property containing a function* -- they are exactly the same thing!  You create methods by assigning functions to properties.

In *this particular case*, you can access the function object through the prototype and apply it to the object, but this is a *terrible* hack.

```
Time.prototype.format.apply(some_time_object);
```

You would be better off storing the method and the value in differently-named properties.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. The only property which will remain will be the string, the function will not exist in any instantiated objects.

Either name them differently, the method could be `formatAs`, or have a function with no arguments return the format:

```
function Time() {
  this.currentformat = 'x:y:z';
}

Time.prototype.format = function (format) {
  if (typeof format === "undefined"){
    return this.currentformat;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of a getter-setter function which gets the value if there is no parameter and sets it if there is one, but in this case I think his format() function returns the time according to said format, so it can't act as a getter.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Yes it can. Why not?

Comment: I think `instance.format()` is supposed to return `12:56:01`, so it can't also return `x:y:z`. But I might be misinterpreting what he's trying to do.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Ah, makes sense; my first instinct was that it would set the format string to the argument, so `instance.format('x:z:y')` would change the `instance.format` property. Your way makes more sense, but then why is there an argument on the format method?

Answer (score 1):

Functions are actually objects stored in properties in JavaScript, so that's not possible.

When you call `instance.format()`, the interpreter looks at the instance to see if it has a property called `format`. If there is, it checks if it's a function and throws an error if it isn't. If the instance doesn't have such a property, it checks the instance's prototype and does the same thing, until an ancestor has a `format` property or until it reaches the top of the inheritance tree. In your situation, it will always try to execute the string, which will cause an error. The interpreter never looks at the prototype for its `format()` method.

You could rename the property to `formatString` or `mask` if you prefer.